# Sonar - JavaSquidSensor is terribly slow

Tags: java, sonarqube

Using SonarQube 5.6.1, activated almost each available rule in the Java Analyzer (v4.2 - quality profile [is attached here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9royh8gzen0g5e3/java-default-profile-73160.xml?dl=0)), the build and analysis of a big project (~2M LoC), which used to run in less than 3h, now takes more than 12h (!). The profiling logs shows the following:

```
[INFO]  ======== Profiling of total execution: 647min 3s ========
[INFO] 
[INFO]  * Module execution time breakdown: 
[INFO]    o Xxx 1.15.4-PCF execution time:                      642min 42s (99%)
[INFO]    o Yyy 1.15.4-PCF execution time:                 3min 58s (0%)
[INFO]    o Zzz 1.15.4-PCF execution time:                     20s (0%)
[INFO]    o Xxxx 1.15.4-PCF execution time:                       395ms (0%)
[INFO]    o Yyyy 1.15.4-PCF execution time:       252ms (0%)
[INFO]    o Zzzz execution time:                  244ms (0%)
[INFO] 
[INFO]  * Sensors execution time:                                  642min 48s (99%)
[INFO]  * Publish report execution time:                             3min 53s (0%)
[INFO]  * Index filesystem execution time:                                13s (0%)
[INFO]  * Computing duplications execution time:                           5s (0%)
[INFO]  * Init issue exclusions execution time:                          26ms (0%)
[INFO]  * Clean memory execution time:                                   18ms (0%)
[INFO]  * Initializers execution time:                                    2ms (0%)
[INFO]  * Post-Jobs execution time:                                       0ms (0%)
[INFO] 
[INFO]  * Sensors execution time breakdown:                        642min 48s
[INFO]    o JavaSquidSensor:                                       571min 45s (88%)
[INFO]    o SCM Sensor:                                              52min 6s (8%)
[INFO]    o FindBugs Sensor:                                         16min 4s (2%)
[INFO]    o CPD Block Indexer:                                            47s (0%)
[INFO]    o JavaScript Squid Sensor:                                      34s (0%)
[INFO]    o JaCoCoSensor:                                                 25s (0%)
[INFO]    o JaCoCoOverallSensor:                                          20s (0%)
[INFO]    o Code Colorizer Sensor:                                        15s (0%)
[INFO]    o JaCoCoItSensor:                                               11s (0%)
[INFO]    o Zero Coverage Sensor:                                          3s (0%)
[INFO] 
[INFO]  ======== End of profiling of total execution ========
```

Obviously, ~10h spent in the JavaSquidSensor is far more than acceptable.

We did an upgrade recently from SonarQube 5.4 to 5.6.1. The Java plugin has been upgraded too, but I don't remember which version it was before the upgrade. Since then, I can see that significant degradation of performance.

How can I track down which particular rule is causing that (other than plain old dichotomy... no time to spend on this)

Using a profiler in a smaller analysis, I wasn't able to identify a bottleneck - the implementation seems deeeply recursive, and most of the time is spent in Visitor classes - see the screenshot attached [image: some profiling].

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I should add that using the built-in configuration (Quality Profile "Sonar way"), the timing fall down to a more viable value

Comment: This seems to me that this is related to this issue : https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarqube/riw7PcJeRx4/zPOMQXJPBQAJ 

So not related directly to a rule AFAI can tell. Would you be able to share a more complete trace of the analysis ? 
As per identifying a rule, i'm afraid you don't have another solution than dichotomy. However you could try to keep only one rule activated (Null Dereference for instance : https://sonarqube.com/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2259 ) and double check if issue is still here.

Comment: I will run a more complete analysis tonight, and give you the results tomorrow. BTW, thanks for the links, it could indeed be related to my issues :)

Comment: Ok, with a bit deeper analysis, it was obvious for my use case which rule was consuming all the time. It was the squid:S1451 (Copyright and headers should be defined) with a regexp which add a really significant overhead, presumably when the file to check do not match the regexp. I guess that depending of the regexp, it could require to parse the whole file before raising a violation. Now the performance are good enough. Thanks Nico for your time

Comment: @spi is this profiling way deprecated in 6.7.1 or this is from a custom plugin? I cant dump this way in INFO logging ?